# How to expose list of custom objects with Q_PROPERTY

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have a very simple class with 2 properties; key and value:

**KeyValue.h:**

```
class KeyValue : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QString key READ getKey WRITE setKey NOTIFY keyChanged)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString value READ getValue WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)

 public:
  KeyValue(const QString& key, const QString& value, QObject* parent = 0);  

 signals:
  void keyChanged();
  void valueChanged();

 private:
  QString _key;
  QString _value;

  QString getKey() const;
  QString getValue() const;

  void setKey(const QString& key);  
  void setValue(const QString& value);
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(KeyValue)
```

In another class I would like a property containing a list of KeyValue objects, so I can use this list as a model in QML.

**Controller.h**

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QList<KeyValue*> items READ getItems NOTIFY itemsChanged)

 public:
  explicit Controller(QObject* parent = 0);

 signals:
  void itemsChanged(); 

 private:
  QList<KeyValue*> getItems() const;
};
```

I want to be able to use this in QML the following way:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import customqml 1.0

Item{
  Controller{
    id: controller
  }
  Repeater{
    model: controller.items
    Text{
      text: modelData.key + ": " + modelData.value
    }
  }
}
```

Both classes are registered in my main.cpp file:

```
qmlRegisterType<KeyValue>("customqml", 1, 0, "KeyValue");
qmlRegisterType<Controller>("customqml", 1, 0, "Controller");
```

The above code does not work, bacause I apparently can't expose a QList to QML directly. I have tried using QAbstractItemModel and QQmlListProperty, but I was unable to get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My primary issues are the type of the *items* property in the Controller class and the return value of the *getItems* method.

I'm using Qt 5.9 if that makes any difference.

Comment: You can use `QVariantList`. But since you want to use it as model in QML you should use a `QAbstractListModel`-descendent. Very comfortable to use is the QQmlObjectListModel that you can find here: https://github.com/Cavewhere/lib-qt-qml-tricks/tree/master/include *disclaimer: I am not the author, just a user.* It might also be possible after `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(KeyValueList)` and the respective typedef, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Please read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html You can use QObjectList or QVariantList, or subclass QAbstractItemModel.

Comment: Thanks for the link @derM. I didn't use that model directly, but the source code was great inspiration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note:

- The getters and setters are generally public except for exceptions so move it to the public part
- The classes that inherit from QObject do not need QMetaType because when you want to transfer data of that class the pointers are used.

Not all data types are supported by QML through Q_PROPERTY, so a possible solution is to export through known classes such as

- **`QList<QObject *>`**:

---

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject *> items READ getItems NOTIFY itemsChanged)
public:
    explicit Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QList<QObject *> getItems() const;
signals:
    void itemsChanged();
private:
    QList<KeyValue *>key_values_list;
};
```

---

```
...
QList<QObject *> Controller::getItems() const
{
    QObjectList l;
    for(auto e: key_values_list)
        l << e;
    return l;
}
```

- **`QVariantList`**:

---

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList items READ getItems NOTIFY itemsChanged)
public:
    explicit Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QVariantList getItems() const;
signals:
    void itemsChanged();
private:
    QList<KeyValue *>key_values_list;
};
```

---

```
...
QVariantList Controller::getItems() const
{
    QVariantList l;
    for(auto e: key_values_list)
        l.append(QVariant::fromValue(e));
    return l;
}
```

Other options is to implement a model, the following example shows only a read-only model:

**keyvaluemodel.h**

```
#ifndef KEYVALUEMODEL_H
#define KEYVALUEMODEL_H

#include "keyvalue.h"

#include <QAbstractListModel>

class KeyValueModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit KeyValueModel(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QAbstractListModel(parent)
    {
        key_values_list = {new KeyValue{"k", "v"}, new KeyValue{"k2", "v2"}};
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return key_values_list.length();
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return QVariant();
        if(index.row() >= 0 && index.row() < rowCount())
            return QVariant::fromValue(key_values_list[index.row()]);
        return QVariant();
    }
private:
    QList<KeyValue* >key_values_list;
};

#endif // KEYVALUEMODEL_H
```

---

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(KeyValueModel* items READ getItems NOTIFY itemsChanged)
public:
    explicit Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    KeyValueModel* getItems() const;
signals:
    void itemsChanged();
private:
    KeyValueModel *model;
};
```

---

```
...
Text{
    text: display.key + ": " + display.value
}
...
```

And in a similar way you can implement a QQmlListProperty, in the docs there are many examples.

Comment: Subclassing QAbstractListModel was just what I needed :)

Comment: Thanks, man, I was stuck in the same issue, I was migrating my project from qt6 to qt5, in qt6 QList<Custom> was working perfectly, but in qt5 it wasn't.

Comment: After doing any of this on the C++ end, be sure to use `modelData` in Repeater QML (as shown in the question)!  I had `model.someProperty` instead of `modelData.someProperty` in my QML side of this and banged my head on the wall for while before realizing that was my damn problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sophisticated model with adding/deleting objects and altering data you should look into subclassing [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html).

As a simple but less flexible way you can use a [QVariantList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) and make your Controller class a value type. You need:

- The macro Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Controller) at the end of the Controller header file.
- A copy constructor for Controller
- A default constructor for Controller

Q_PROPERTY Type and return value are then QVariantList.

Comment: There is no sense in making the `Controller` a value-based class. It would then be impossible to have signals in it. It is likely that the `KeyValue` could be a `Q_GADGET` if it would be unnecessary to have changed-signals.

Comment: That's why the primary recommendation is subclassing QAbstractListModel. For objects without changing data or signals the value type can be helpful. I did not know Q_GADGET yet, thanks for the hint.